# Will the Screen fit to all devices if i use margin top's and margin bottom's in XML in Android

Tags: android, device

I am developing an application in which i need to use lot of text-views and i am using a relative layout.Since i positioned my text-views in different coordinates(margintop=20dp),will the layout fit for all the android devices(tabs,Nook color phones,normal devices etc)

Any suggestions are highly appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, that shouldn't be a problem. To clarify your doubt, follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence) link. The first point explains your doubt.